# new BrokeredMessage(object) returns System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, azure, serialization, azureservicebus

I am following this tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/

I have this object that I'm trying to send as a message:

```
[Serializable]
public class LeadSubmissionMessage
{
    public long LeadId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Where "message" is an instance of LeadSubmissionMessage... Supposedly, this is should serialize the message:

```
BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message);
```

This compiles, and it does not throw an error at runtime. But the message never hits the service bus.  In stepping through the code in debug and looking at brokeredMessage in Watch, it is full of errors.  Lots of instances of this error:

```
brokeredMessage  threw an exception of type System.InvalidOperationException 
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
```

[image]

In doing some Google work, I have seen other people have this same issue, but none of them seem to have ever found a resolution.  I am starting to wonder if this is a bug.

Comment: Have you tried with `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes instead of `Serializable`?

Comment: Yes.  Same result.  I'm now thinking it isn't about the object  because if I make the message a simple string ("this is a test"), I get the same result.

Comment: Have you tried recreating the queue, is it enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled and active

Comment: You can also use visual studio's (and you have latest azure sdk) server explorer to send a test message from you service bus topic

Comment: Service Bus Explorer is also usefull tool: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Service-Bus-Explorer-f2abca5a

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Comment: Oh man Neo -- sorry!  Too long ago.  I don't recall.  Usually when I find the solution I come back and post the answer.  I wish I had done this here too.  Sorry! If you figure it out, please post the answer here and I'll happily mark it as such.